# Viewing pdf large files online as thumbnail

Tags: pdf, jquery

I need to upload a pdf file in my website so that users can view/download it. But it is of 30MB file. So when the user clicks on that downloadable link it takes much time to download. So I was just thinking is there any other solution for this so that users can atleast view and read the contents of the file without downloading it and if required they can download it. ??

one suggestion is like onclick of downloadable link  one new link will open where user can view pages individual as thumbnail and on click it will zoom and below we will give download link(as in google ebooks). But I was just wondering how this can be done?? Is it possible using jquery/ajax?? Please give your thoughts on this and any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to upload your PDF at http://view.samurajdata.se and then include the viewer for your PDF in an iframe.

If you like, you can even take the viewer link (something like `http://view.samurajdata.se/psview.php?id=YOUR_PDF_ID`), and get URLs for the individual pages as GIFs like `http://view.samurajdata.se/rsc/YOUR_PDF_ID/tmp1.gif` for page 1, tmp2.gif for page 2, etc. Then you can embed those GIFs how you want and customize the look and feel of your viewer.

Comment: Oh, and your PDF will get purged if it's not viewed for 3 days. It would be kind of rude, but maybe you could schedule something to access it every 2 1/2 days, or something to detect on-the-fly if the document has been purged and re-upload and update your URLs.